# How can I get the name of my form's controls in the .html file?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am saving the name of my form controls in a list. To check if the form controls are valid, I need to concatenate their names with my code in the html file. How can I do it?

Here is my code:

.ts file

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
   item0: ['', Validators.required],
   item1: ['', Validators.required]
});

formControls: string[] = [];
this.formControls.push('item0');
this.formControls.push('item1');
```

.html file

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div *ngFor="let item of formControls">
    <input formControlName="{{item}}"
     [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.item.errors }"/><!-- it must be: f.item0.errors, f.item1.errors-->
    <label>{{item}}</label>
    <div *ngIf="f.item.errors" class="invalid-feedback"> 
      <div *ngIf="f.item.errors.required">
        Item is required
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string interpolation` to concatenate the form control names with the `formGroup` directive

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of formControls"> 
  <input [formControlName]="item"
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': form.get(item)?.invalid }" />

   <div *ngIf="form.get(item)?.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="form.get(item)?.errors.required"> 
      <label> {{item}} </label> is required 
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code example : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-12-e4xy4k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an additional array to store the form control name.

Iterate the controls in the `FormGroup` via `*ngFor` and `KeyValuePipe`.

```
<div *ngFor="let kvp of (form.controls | keyvalue)">
  <input
    [formControlName]="kvp.key"
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': kvp.value.errors }"
  />
  <label>{{kvp.key}}</label>
  <div *ngIf="kvp.value.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="kvp.value.errors['required']">Item is required</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nxtmze?file=src%2Fmain.html)